# Java: Can Vector<derived> be called as Vector<base>?

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

I've got a class foo, a class that derives from food called bar, and I've got a method in foo that takes another foo

```
boolean baz(foo c)
{
return (condition)?true:false;
}
```

I want to write an overload for baz that takes a Vector and calls baz on all of them -- something like

```
boolean baz(Vector<foo> v)
{
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)
    {
    if baz(v.get(i))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and I want to use call this method on a Vector of bar. I tried writing this in the way I just outlined, and I get compiler errors when I try to call this method on a vector of bar.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the exact compiler error?  This will help people identify the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-polymorphic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected, because generics are invariant.

`List<Derived>` is not `List<Base>`. Imagine if you call that method, but inside it you call `list.add(anotherDerived)`.

You can "fix" this by using `List<? extends Base>`. Thus you won't be able to add elements, and hence won't be able to violate the generics contract.

(I'm using `List` instead of `Vector`, because `Vector` is replaced (in most cases) by `ArrayList`)

Answer (score 6):

Just declare the method like this:

```
boolean baz(Vector<? extends foo> v)
```

Two additional points:

- Java has an extremely strong convention for class names beginning with an uppercase letter. Anyone reading your code will be irritated by lowercase class names.
- `Vector` is an obsolete class that should not be used anymore unless you're dealing with an API that does and which you don't control (like some parts of AWT). Use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I know about the uppercase class name convention and use it in my own code. I just haven't internalized it to the degree that I automatically used it in my example :). Thanks for the hint about vector, though!

Answer (score 1):

instead of :

```
boolean baz(Vector<foo> v)
```

try

```
boolean baz(Vector<? extends foo> v)
```